# android EditText crash app

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext

I start from a empty application. Just the minimum. And i only put a editText. When i run on a emulator, both Genymotion and android studio emulators, it's work perfectly. But when i try on my device (samsung galaxy S5 API 21), the app stop without any other behavior....

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

And for the MainActivity:

```
package com.lipszyc.jeremy.exemplecrash;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it say in the logcat when the app crashes?

Comment: Yes. Please post your logcat. Also are gradle dependencies properly setup?

Answer (score 0):

Never seen constraints, but do you have a layout with the id activity_main? If so, shouldn't those values be @id and not @+id?

Are your themes also based on appcompat? Do you have any actionbars and toolbars existing in the same layout?

As others have said, a logcat will help.